# Issue with WPF Popup and button's tooltip

Tags: .net, wpf, button, popup, tooltip

I am working on a WPF C# application and I need to create a popup, that contains a button, and for that button i need to define a tooltip.

The issue is, when i hover over the button, the tooltip appears, but when i move the mouse away, the tooltip does not disappear immediately, it takes about 5 seconds to disappear.

Below the code snippet:

```
        <ToggleButton Name="PART_Button"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                      Width="20"
                      Height="20"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=PART_Popup, 
                      Path=IsOpen, Mode=OneWay}">
        </ToggleButton>

        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PART_Button, Path=IsChecked}"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_Button}"
               StaysOpen="False">

            <Button x:Name="PART_MinButton"
                    Content="BOT">

                <Button.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Placement="Bottom"
                             Content="Hello !!" />                       
                </Button.ToolTip>

            </Button>

        </Popup>
```

I have got a clue, so when i do remove StaysOpen="False", the tooltip works well for the inside button and it disappears immediately when i move the mouse away, but when i set StaysOpen="False" the issue begins.

Does anybody know how can i fix this please ? i am stuck and running out of ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the ShowDuration attached property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showduration(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, but that defines what time should the tooltip remain visible, my issue is when i move the mouse away from the button, it does not disappear immediately , it takes a while before that.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know how can i fix this please ?

You could handle the `MouseLeave` event for the `Button`.

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PART_Button, Path=IsChecked}"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_Button}"
               StaysOpen="False">
    <Button x:Name="PART_MinButton"
                    Content="BOT" MouseLeave="PART_MinButton_MouseLeave">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="False"
                     Content="Hello !!" />
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
</Popup>
```

---

```
private void PART_MinButton_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    (btn.ToolTip as ToolTip).IsOpen = false;
}
```